# Understanding some proof in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis

I have been studying analysis from Rudin and I have grown used to the succinct presentation of the proofs. However, I have started reading Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Spaces and it is hard for me to understand the rigour. Primarily, his arguments are mainly based on "arbitrarily" which doesnt make much sense. For example, for the proof that

> If the $A_k$'s are disjoint then $$\lambda_*(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}A_k) \geq \sum^\infty_ {k=1}\lambda_* (A_k)$$ where $A_k$ is an arbitrary set.

He writes

> If $K_1,...K_N$ are any compact subsets of $A_1,..., A_N$, respectively, then they are disjoint. Therefore, Property C4 implies 
>   $$\lambda_*(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}A_k) \geq \lambda_*(\bigcup^K_{k=1}A_k) =\sum^K_ {k=1}\lambda_* (K_k)$$
>   Since the $K_k$'s are arbitrary hence 
>   $$\lambda_*(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}A_k) \geq \sum^N_ {k=1}\lambda_* (A_k)$$
>   Since $N$ is arbitrary, hence proved.

Now I understand what the proof is saying, that since $K_k$ is arbitrary hence we can replace it with $A_k$ and since $N$ is arbitrary hence we can replace it with any number and thus potentially infinite.

But I am worried about the rigor. Can somebody provide me a construction of an argument that primarily relies on predicate logical quantifiers and qualifiers and not on "arbitrary"?

Lastly is this kind of proof correct?

> For each $A_K$, arbitrarily take a $K_k \subset A_K$ such that $\lambda_*(A_k) - \lambda(K_k) < \epsilon/N $
>   $$\sum^N \lambda_*(A_k) <\sum^N \lambda(K_k + \epsilon/N) = \sum^N \lambda(K_k) + \epsilon =\lambda(\bigcup^N K_k) +\epsilon \leq sup \{\lambda ( \bigcup^N K_k ) | \bigcup^N K_k \subset \bigcup^N A_k \} + \epsilon =  \lambda( \bigcup^N A_k) + \epsilon \leq \lambda( \bigcup^\infty A_k) + \epsilon   $$
>   Since $\epsilon$ and $N$ are arbitrary hence 
>   $$\sum^\infty_ {k=1}\lambda_* (A_k) \leq \lambda_*(\bigcup^\infty_{k=1}A_k)  $$
>   Hence proved.

I am a bit critical of the statement "$\lambda_*(A_k) - \lambda(K_k) < \epsilon/N $" but I have seen the book use this statement repeatedly in its proof. The main thing I am concerned is whether its justified to state that 
"$\lambda_*(A_k) - \lambda(K_k) < \epsilon/N $ and $K_k$ is arbitrary hence $\lambda_*(A_k) \leq \lambda(K_k)$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Arbitrary" usually translates to "for all" ($\forall$), but sometimes an object is arbitrarily picked from a set and, for the rest of the proof, is held fixed.  And, with enough complexity, this can be hard to keep track of.

So let me recommend a radical solution: instead of Rudin, use B. Vulikh's [Brief course in the theory of functions of a real variable](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_brief_course_in_the_theory_of_function.html?id=qF06AAAAMAAJ).  It is a monograph, but there are exercises in [Introductory Real Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=cbbCAgAAQBAJ&dq=kolmogorov+fomin+introductory+real+analysis&source=gbs_navlinks_s), which is also a very good book on analysis, but its chapters on measure and integration have a few kinks in the translation that get in the way of understanding, imho.  As for the other topics, Kolmogorov and Fomin are great.

For measure and integration, Vulikh's book, in my experience, is unequaled in transparency, cleanliness, and brevity of exposition.  For one, he uses $\sigma$-rings instead of $\sigma$-algebras, and as a result a whole lot of constructs and proofs (including measure continuity and the construction of the Lebesgue measure) become a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that arbitrary stands for "for all".  What I am concerned is about the order of the quantifier. Like how do I know that, that for all isn't dependent upon like something "there exists"?

Comment: Right, that's what I consider hard to keep track of: the reader needs to hold in memory all the stipulations and interdependencies made before the "arbitrary" shpiel.  And Rudin seems to have no mercy on the reader.

Trust me, you shouldn't have to spend time deciphering the writing: the subject itself has enough to occupy you.  Read Vulikh, save yourself a lot of time and confusion, and increase the effectiveness of your studies.